# Android, ListView items become unclickable

Tags: android, list, listview, click

I am connecting a ListView to a Detail Activity so that the user can click on a list item, go to a more detailed view, and then go back.  Everything is working fine, except that at times I can no longer click on list items at all.  The emulator will not recognize clicks on the listview if I click on one button that hides all other elements (setVisibility(View.GONE)).  I have to click on other elements before the listview will handle interactions again.  In the stack, if this line is at the bottom, the listview is unclickable:

```
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2383490
```

I've seen it before but I haven't paid much attention to it until now. Can someone explain what this means and if it could be a sign of my problem, or if it is negligible.

For reference, this is the visibility changer that causes the issue:

```
//      Onclick method for Notes Collapse button
    final Button buttonN = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.notesSectionHeading);
    buttonN.setTag(0);
    final LinearLayout inputButtons = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.input_control_block);
    final LinearLayout inputBlock = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_block);
    buttonN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   public void onClick(View v) {

           final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
           if (status == 1) {
               v.setTag(0); //pause
               inputBlock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               inputButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           } else {
               v.setTag(1); //pause
               inputBlock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               inputButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }

           Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "View visibility changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   }
        }

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try seting your buttons(or any other views you want to handle click inside a list item) like this:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

It should work

Comment: No luck unfortunately, I also tried giving another element focus, but regardless of how many times you click it won't register until some other element has been touched.  If you just scroll the list it'll work, but not unless you do.